# How to store dynamically input name and value both in Controller

Tags: laravel

This is my blade file where the input type is a radio and I have made name dynamically by giving question id so that I can store in question_id. So How can I store them in Controller.

```
@foreach($question->answers as $index=> $answer)
 <span>
    <input type="radio" name="{{$question->id}}" value="{{$answer->id}}" id="answer{{$question->id}}" 
       class="clickanswer" data-id="{{$answer->id}}">
         {{$index+1}}) {!! $answer->answer_body !!}
 </span>
@endforeach
```

Now this is my Controller

```
 public function quizTest(Request $request){
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data=$request->all();
        foreach($data as $question_id => $answer_id){
            dd($data);
                $result=new Result;
                $result->user_id=$data['user_id'];
               $result->question_id=$question_id;
               $result->answer_id=$answer_id;
               $result->save();
        }

    }
}
```

Now when I do dd($data); and I want to store data like 1 2 3 4 5 in question_id and 2,6,9,13,18 in answer_id

[image: Now I want to store data like 1 2 3 4 5 in question_id and 2,6,9,13,18 in answer_id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller code to this to store it in answer and question format

```
public function quizTest(Request $request){
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data=$request->all();
        $user_id = $data['user_id'];
        unset($data['_token']);
        unset($data['user_id']);
        foreach($data as $question_id => $answer_id){
            $result = new Result;
            $result->user_id = $user_id;
            $result->question_id = $question_id;
            $result->answer_id = $answer_id;
            $result->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SauravShrestha My pleasure